# How to load a website via s3 with pre-signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to block public access to my webapp served via S3 and only allow pre-signed URL to load the website. To do this I have allowed static site hosting in S3, and allowed public read to all objects. This allowed me to load the website public. Then I added a policy to deny access to index.html:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForPublicWebsiteContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::web-portal/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PrivateReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::web-portal/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thereafter I generated a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html) to the index.html page via using the sdk.

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: 'web-portal',
    Key: 'index.html',
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
})
```

However, I get access denied when I try to access the URL provided via the SDK.

[image]

I assume this happens as I added the deny policy to index.html. I would be much obliged to know what is the proper way to implement such a feature with aws s3.

Comment: "static site hosting in S3" requires your website to be public. You can't change that with s3 presigned urls. Thus can you actually explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a restricted site to collect some information from the user, and the link should only work for few minutes and should load the site without any login or restrictions. Therefore I would like to provide a pre-signed URL from the backend and send the user to this pre-signed url. I can do this via adding a random key as query param and reject loading the page via programmatic code. However, I was trying if this feature can be fully handled via AWS S3 itself.

Comment: I see what you want to do. And you are correct, your `Deny` is the issue.

Comment: Could you separate your website into two buckets or folders? Then you would make one bucket public as static website, and in the second one you would have only index.html as private.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try this out.

Comment: Hi @marcin I was able to resolve this by removing the deny policy to index.html, and add a policy to public read access to the rest of the files such as .js and .css. Therefore index.html was not in the default allow list or deny list. Hence I could not load the site publicly, however, when I get a signed URL to index.html I was able to access the index.html and load the rest of the page.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can answer your own question and accept it as well for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by only adding the policy to allow other files (js, css) to be accessed publicly, and not adding any policy (Allow/Deny) to the index.html.

For me all my other files we located under the folder called static. Therefore I added a policy to allow public access to this folder.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForPublicWebsiteContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::web-portal/static/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After adding the above policy you cannot access the index.html page via browser. However you can access the index.html if you have a pre-signed URL. As the other required files are in public domain, the index.html was able to load the rest.

I pressume the same can be done if we can gzip the entier website. Thus all files will reside in one single zip folder. Then provide a pre-signed url to that file. In this way we do not have to enter any bucket policies for other non index files.